# numpy dimensions

Tags: python, numpy

Im a newbie to Numpy and trying to understand the basic question of what is dimension,

I tried the following commands and trying to understand why the ndim for last 2 arrays are same?

```
>>> a= array([1,2,3])
>>> a.ndim
1
>>> a= array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])
>>> a
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6]])
>>> a.ndim
2
>>> a=arange(15).reshape(3,5)
>>> a.ndim
2

>>> a
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
       [10, 11, 12, 13, 14]])
```

My understanding..

```
Case 1:
    array([[1, 2, 3],
           [4, 5, 6]])

2 elements are present in main lists, so ndim is-2

Case 2:
    array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
           [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
           [10, 11, 12, 13, 14]])
```

3 elements are present in the main lists, do ndim is-3

Comment: would be easier to explain if you mentioned what you expected them to be

Comment: `ndim` means "number of dimensions". a 2D array has ndim=2, a 3D array has ndim=3, etc.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `shape` of an array is a tuple of its dimensions. An array with one dimension has a shape of (n,). A two dimension array has a shape of (n,m) (like your case 2 and 3) and a three dimension array has a shape of (n,m,k) and so on.

Therefore, whilst the shape of your second and third example are different, the no. dimensions is two in both cases:

```
>>> a= np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])
>>> a.shape
(2, 3)

>>> b=np.arange(15).reshape(3,5)
>>> b.shape
(3, 5)
```

If you wanted to add another dimension to your examples you would have to do something like this:

```
a= np.array([[[1,2,3]],[[4,5,6]]])
```

or

```
np.arange(15).reshape(3,5,1)
```

You can keep adding dimensions in this way:

One dimension:

```
>>> a = np.zeros((2))
array([ 0.,  0.])
>>> a.shape
(2,)
>>> a.ndim
1
```

Two dimensions:

```
>>> b = np.zeros((2,2))
array([[ 0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.]])
>>> b.shape
(2,2)
>>> b.ndim
2
```

Three dimensions:

```
>>> c = np.zeros((2,2,2))
array([[[ 0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.]],

       [[ 0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  0.]]])
>>> c.shape
(2,2,2)
>>> c.ndim
3
```

Four dimensions:

```
>>> d = np.zeros((2,2,2,2))
array([[[[ 0.,  0.],
         [ 0.,  0.]],

        [[ 0.,  0.],
         [ 0.,  0.]]],


       [[[ 0.,  0.],
         [ 0.,  0.]],

        [[ 0.,  0.],
         [ 0.,  0.]]]])
>>> d.shape
(2,2,2,2)
>>> d.ndim
4
```

Answer (score 0):

While @atomh33ls has a fantastic written answer, I generated this visual to help communicate the differences between a `numpy.ndarray.shape` and a `numpy.ndarray.ndim`.

In this visual, the `ndim` increases as each new slider moves above 1. This is first seen when `m` is set to 1 defining a 1-dimensional `ndarray` with `shape` `(1,)`.

Note that I use `m`, `n`, and `k` in order to represent the length of each additional dimension.

[image]