# Understanding axes in NumPy

Tags: python, numpy

I was going through NumPy [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/user/quickstart.html), and am not able to understand one point. It mentions, for the example below,  the array has rank 2 (it is 2-dimensional). The first dimension (axis) has a length of 2, the second dimension has a length of 3.

```
 [[ 1., 0., 0.],
 [ 0., 1., 2.]]
```

How does the first dimension (axis) have a length of 2?

**Edit:**
The reason for my confusion is the below statement in the documentation.

> The coordinates of a point in 3D space [1, 2, 1] is an array of rank
>   1, because it has one axis. That axis has a length of 3.

In the original 2D ndarray, I assumed that the number of lists identifies the rank/dimension, and I wrongly assumed that the length of each list denotes the length of each dimension (in that order). So, as per my understanding, the first dimension should be having a length of 3, since the length of the first list is 3.

Comment: How many lists are there in the list?

Comment: There are 2 rows and 3 columns in that 2D array, so it has shape (2, 3)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [numpy dimensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16018203/numpy-dimensions)

Comment: I think it's a little poorly chosen on numpy's part to use the word "rank", since matrices mathematically have a notion of rank which is very similar but not the same as this. For example, the matrix [[0,1],[0,1]] is rank 1, not rank 2, mathematically. But that's not what you're asking I guess. Just don't google "matrix rank"

Comment: `rank` isn't in the `index` for `numpy`.  Nor is it in the basic reference page, https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/reference/arrays.html.  Its use on this tutorial page is a quirk.  They probably shouldn't have talked about coordinates in 3d space either.  A `numpy` `array` is an abstract object that can have many dimensions, and each of those may be may be much larger than 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you print the numpy array

```
print(np.array([[ 1.  0.  0.],[ 0.  1.  2.]])
```

You'll get the following output

```
#col1 col2 col3
[[ 1.  0.  0.]  # row 1
[ 0.  1.  2.]] #  row 2
```

Think of it as a 2 by 3 matrix... 2 rows, 3 columns. It is a 2d array because it is a list of lists. ([[ at the start is a hint its 2d)).

The 2d numpy array

```
np.array([[ 1.  0., 0., 6.],[ 0.  1.  2., 7.],[3.,4.,5,8.]])
```

would print as

```
#col1 col2 col3 col4
[[ 1.  0. , 0., 6.]  # row 1
[ 0.  1. , 2., 7.] #  row 2
[3.,  4. , 5., 8.]] # row 3
```

This is a 3 by 4 2d array (3 rows, 4 columns)

Answer (score 6):

In `numpy`, axis ordering follows `zyx` convention, instead of the usual (and maybe more intuitive) `xyz`.

Visually, it means that for a 2D array where the horizontal axis is `x` and the vertical axis is `y`:

```
    x -->
y      0   1   2
|  0 [[1., 0., 0.],
V  1  [0., 1., 2.]]
```

The `shape` of this array is `(2, 3)` because it is ordered `(y, x)`, with the first axis `y` of length `2`.

And verifying this with slicing:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 2]], dtype=np.float)

>>> a
Out[]:
array([[ 1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  2.]])

>>> a[0, :]                    # Slice index 0 of first axis
Out[]: array([ 1.,  0.,  0.])  # Get values along second axis `x` of length 3

>>> a[:, 2]                    # Slice index 2 of second axis
Out[]: array([ 0.,  2.])       # Get values along first axis `y` of length 2
```

Answer (score 2):

You may be confusing the other sentence with the picture example below. Think of it like this: `Rank = number of lists in the list(array)` and the term length in your question can be thought of `length = the number of 'things' in the list(array)`

I think they are trying to describe to you the definition of `shape` which is in this case `(2,3)`

in that post I think the key sentence is here:

> In NumPy dimensions are called axes. The number of axes is rank.

Comment: Much better, imo

Comment: @en_Knight. One more time! you need the [proofreader](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/1276/proofreader) badge

Answer (score 0):

The first dimensions is the length:

```
In [11]: a = np.array([[ 1., 0., 0.], [ 0., 1., 2.]])

In [12]: a
Out[12]:
array([[ 1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  2.]])

In [13]: len(a)  # "length of first dimension"
Out[13]: 2
```

The second is the length of each "row":

```
In [14]: [len(aa) for aa in a]  # 3 is "length of second dimension"
Out[14]: [3, 3]
```

Many numpy functions take axis as an argument, for example you can sum over an axis:

```
In [15]: a.sum(axis=0)
Out[15]: array([ 1.,  1.,  2.])

In [16]: a.sum(axis=1)
Out[16]: array([ 1.,  3.])
```

---

The thing to note is that you can have higher dimensional arrays:

```
In [21]: b = np.array([[[1., 0., 0.], [ 0., 1., 2.]]])

In [22]: b
Out[22]:
array([[[ 1.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 0.,  1.,  2.]]])

In [23]: b.sum(axis=2)
Out[23]: array([[ 1.,  3.]])
```

Comment: Wanted to say _You can think of these as N-dimensional Cartesian space, and these functions as projections... if that helps._ but not sure that's wholly accurate.

Answer (score 0):

Keep the following points in mind when considering Numpy axes:

1. **Each sub-level of a list (or array) represents an axis.** For example:

```py
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1,2])                         # 1 axis
b = np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])                 # 2 axes
c = np.array([[[1,2],[3,4]],[[5,6],[7,8]]]) # 3 axes
```

2. **Axis labels correspond to the level of the sub-list they represent**, starting with axis `0` for the outer most list.

   To illustrate this, consider the following array of different shape, **each with 24 elements**:

```py
# 1D Array
a0 = np.array(
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24]
)
a0.shape # (24,) - here, the length along the 0-axis is 24 

# 2D Array
a01 = np.array(
    [
     [1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4],
     [2.1, 2.2, 2.3, 2.4],
     [3.1, 3.2, 3.3, 3.4],
     [4.1, 4.2, 4.3, 4.4],
     [5.1, 5.2, 5.3, 5.4],
     [6.1, 6.2, 6.3, 6.4]
    ]

)
a01.shape # (6, 4) - now, the length along the 0-axis is 6

# 3D Array
a012 = np.array(


    [
     [
      [1.1.1, 1.1.2],
      [1.2.1, 1.2.2],
      [1.3.1, 1.3.2]
     ],
     [
      [2.1.1, 2.1.2],
      [2.2.1, 2.2.2],
      [2.3.1, 2.3.2]
     ],
     [
      [3.1.1, 3.1.2],
      [3.2.1, 3.2.2],
      [3.3.1, 3.3.2]
     ],
     [
      [4.1.1, 4.1.2],
      [4.2.1, 4.2.2],
      [4.3.1, 4.3.2]
     ]
)
a012.shape # (4, 3, 2) - and finally, the length along the 0-axis is 4
```