# Understanding Numpy rot90 axes

Tags: python, numpy

Numpy's rot90 function promises to rotate a 2d or higher array by 90 degrees, taking an axes parameter. The method:

```
numpy.rot90(m, k=1, axes=(0, 1))[source]

Rotate an array by 90 degrees in the plane specified by axes. 
Rotation direction is from the first towards the second axis.
```

I'm very confused about the axes part. An object can be rotated around the x, y, or z axis. Typically, this is defined by something such as a Vector3f, with 3 floats defining the axis value (ex, (0, 0, 1) to rotate around z axis.) I do not understand how these two numbers can be used to  rotate a 3d object, shouldn't it be 3 like a Vector3f? Can anyone help me understand what these two axes mean, and what two numbers would be used for, respectively, rotation around the x, y, and z axis? I've tried many different combinations of numbers and they all have various results (I can't put in two of the same numbers), but I have no idea how it's possible to have enough information with two numbers (k represents amount of times to rotate.)

Comment: https://www.w3resource.com/numpy/manipulation/rot90.php

Comment: I took a look at that already but I'm still confused what the numbers "mean". In a Vector3f for example, I know each number represents the axis. I don't understand how (0, 1) alone is enough for describing an axis.

Comment: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.rot90.html   see the last example on this page. It is using 1, 2 as the axis parameter

Comment: In 3 d you got rotation about a plane. I think it must be rotation about y-z plane but ya I too feel there could be a more clear definition and if you see there it's a new feature.Maybe asking it on github would be a better option.

Comment: If you print your_array.shape  , you ll get the shape as a tuple representing the axes. So you get the count of elements along axes

Comment: Alright, I'll give the Numpy github a try.

Comment: Yeah, the 3d rotation part seems very confusing.

Comment: Describe your `m` array.  What's your concept of `x,y,z` axes in this context?

Comment: well, I no longer think it would be confusing, 0->x 1->y z->3

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46855793/understanding-axes-in-numpy See this post for how axes are described in numpy

Comment: hpaulj my m array is a 3d array made from a regular python array. The dimensiosn are 16 * 16 * 16. I imagine it as a cube in space.

VisheshMangla Shouldn't it be z->2? If that's the case, along with the link, it should be easy to do!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I like to work with a sample array with distinct values and dimensions, such as `np.arange(24).reshape(2,3,4)`.

In this case I also looked at the code.  After some preliminaries to make sure `axes` and `k` are right it does different things depending on the 4 possible values of `k`.

`axes` define a "plane".  With a 3d array, `axes=(0,1)` can be thought of as rotation about the third axes (2), imagining a "vector" perpendicular to that "plane".  But it's these axes values that used in the code.  While I suspect we could construct equivalent operations with trig based rotation matrices, this code does not do any calculations.  (Note that integers are not changed to floats.)

`k=0` changes nothing:

```
In [104]: np.rot90(m,k=0, axes=(0,1))
Out[104]: 
array([[[ 0,  1,  2,  3],         # shape (2,3,4)
        [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
        [ 8,  9, 10, 11]],

       [[12, 13, 14, 15],
        [16, 17, 18, 19],
        [20, 21, 22, 23]]])
```

`k=1` involves a flip followed by a transpose

```
In [105]: np.rot90(m,k=1, axes=(0,1))
Out[105]: 
array([[[ 8,  9, 10, 11],           # shape (3,2,4)
        [20, 21, 22, 23]],

       [[ 4,  5,  6,  7],
        [16, 17, 18, 19]],

       [[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
        [12, 13, 14, 15]]])
```

`k=2` is simpler - just a flip on both axes.  This is easy to visualize.  Last dimension is unchanged (across rows), but planes and rows are reversed:

```
In [106]: np.rot90(m,k=2, axes=(0,1))
Out[106]: 
array([[[20, 21, 22, 23],
        [16, 17, 18, 19],
        [12, 13, 14, 15]],

       [[ 8,  9, 10, 11],
        [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
        [ 0,  1,  2,  3]]])
```

`k=3` does the flip first, then the transpose

```
In [107]: np.rot90(m,k=3, axes=(0,1))
Out[107]: 
array([[[12, 13, 14, 15],         # again (3,2,4)
        [ 0,  1,  2,  3]],

       [[16, 17, 18, 19],
        [ 4,  5,  6,  7]],

       [[20, 21, 22, 23],
        [ 8,  9, 10, 11]]])
```

Looking at the strides:

```
In [111]: m.strides
Out[111]: (96, 32, 8)
In [112]: np.rot90(m,k=2, axes=(0,1)).strides
Out[112]: (-96, -32, 8)                # the double flip
```

The transpose switches the order, while the flip again changes the sign:

```
In [113]: np.rot90(m,k=1, axes=(0,1)).strides
Out[113]: (-32, 96, 8)
In [114]: np.rot90(m,k=3, axes=(0,1)).strides
Out[114]: (32, -96, 8)
```

Because it just uses `flip` and `transpose` the result is a `view`.

## Simpler (1,3,4) array

It may be easier to visualize in an array that represents values in one plane, a (3,4) array:

```
In [120]: m = np.arange(12).reshape(1,3,4)
In [121]: m
Out[121]: 
array([[[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
        [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
        [ 8,  9, 10, 11]]])
In [122]: np.rot90(m,k=2, axes=(1,2))
Out[122]: 
array([[[11, 10,  9,  8],
        [ 7,  6,  5,  4],
        [ 3,  2,  1,  0]]])
In [123]: np.rot90(m,k=1, axes=(1,2))  # visualize a counterclockwise rotation
Out[123]: 
array([[[ 3,  7, 11],
        [ 2,  6, 10],
        [ 1,  5,  9],
        [ 0,  4,  8]]])
In [124]: np.rot90(m,k=3, axes=(1,2))    # clockwise
Out[124]: 
array([[[ 8,  4,  0],
        [ 9,  5,  1],
        [10,  6,  2],
        [11,  7,  3]]])
```

`k=3` can also be visualized as successive counterclockwise rotations through 1 and 2.